# How to make SQLAlchemy Transaction.rollback() drop tables it created?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I want unit tests to cleanup after themselves.
For this purpose I use SQLAlchemy's Transaction.rollback() method. Which indeed rollbacks any changes in tables' contents.
However, tables that **were created during** the transaction are not dropped.
Is there any elegant way to achieve auto-dropping created tables with transaction rollback?

The backend DBMS is Oracle in this case.
After reading the docs I suspect the implicit commit after DDL operations in Oracle. This breaks the transaction concept

Comment: In general, I don't think that rollback will roll back table creation. SQL has two basic branches, DDL & DML. Statements like CREATE TABLE are considered data definition language (DDL) and aren't affected by transactions. Statements like INSERT and UPDATE, on the other hand, are data manipulation language (DML) and these are covered by transactions. I'm doing what you need in my testing module and I have to do the DDL separately from my transactions, manually deleting the new tables when the tests are done (or, in my case, altering,  rather than deleting).

Comment: This is exactly what happens. DDL just doesn’t count during rollbacks. I implemented manual cleanup (table drops) just like you did, and it does the job well. Thanks!